# Getting a 500 Internal server error dash with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, internal-server-error

I am trying to create a dashboard with the python libraries `dash` and `plotly`. I have successfully created a static html dashboard, but when I try to add a plotly graph instead of plain html I get a `500 Internal Server Error`. My code is as follows:

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

app = dash.Dash()

# Creating data

np.random.seed(42)
random_x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)
random_y = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)

data = [go.Trace(
    x = random_x,
    y = random_y,
    mode = 'lines'
)]

layout = go.Layout(title = 'bello')


app.lyaout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id = 'lineplot', figure = {'data': data, 'layout': layout})])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

This outputs this when I try to access the webpage:

```sh
raise exceptions.NoLayoutException(
dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException: The layout was `None` at the time that `run_server` was called.
Make sure to set the `layout` attribute of your application
before running the server.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already figured out, it is just a typo error on line 24. It should be `app.layout` instead of `app.lyaout`.

(not related to this question): By the way, it is a good practice not to have space around `=` in named parameters/keyword argument, unlike assignment operator `=`.

e.g.

```
random_x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 100) // assignment OK
layout = go.Layout(title = 'bello') // named parameter KO. Should be title='bello'
```

Comment: yes, I am sorry about that. I really should have not posted.